# convert authors names to unique numbers in json file

Tags: python

I have a json file which is a coauthorship network. Entries are like this:

```
[
["Alin Deutsch", "Mary F. Fernandez", 1998],
["Alin Deutsch", "Daniela Florescu", 1998],
["Alin Deutsch", "Alon Y. Levy", 1998],
["Alin Deutsch", "Dan Suciu", 1998],

...
]
```

I want to replace all the authors names with unique numbers as I want the output in csv file to be like this:

```
1,2,1998
1,3,1998
1,4,1998
1,5,1998
```

So, how can I do this using python?

Comment: What have you tried until now? What problems did you face?

Comment: You could use the built-in [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) function on the author's information, or perhaps one of the functions in the [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) module.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

xs = [['Alin Deutsch', 'Mary F. Fernandez', 1998],
      ['Alin Deutsch', 'Daniela Florescu', 1998],
      ['Alin Deutsch', 'Alon Y. Levy', 1998],
      ['Alin Deutsch', 'Dan Suciu', 1998]]

df = pd.DataFrame(xs)

authors = set(df[0]).union(set(df[1]))
authors_dict = {auth: i for i, auth in enumerate(authors, start=1)}

df[0] = df[0].replace(authours_dict)
df[1] = df[1].replace(authours_dict)
```

Comment: you can do df[0].map(authors_dict) and pandas will take care of the correct mapping back to the column value